# boost makeshared expects 1 arugments 4 provided

Tags: c++, boost

I'm getting the following error when compiling boost

```
boost::make_shared(const A1 &)' : expects 1 arguments - 4 provided
```

Comment: You **must** have scrambled that: the error message is surely not generated by that code (unless, of course, `const A1 &` envokes some hideous macros that explode to 4 arguments)

Comment: You have a line in your code with `make_shared` function call and you passing 4 arguments in it. Find it and refactor it or paste here for review